# Citing multiple references using natbib in ShareLatex

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using this piece of code (as suggested by various questions/answers on tex.stackexchange.com.

```
\documentclass{bioinfo}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
blah blah blah \cite{weiller1998phylogenetic,cokus2007improved,pellegrini1999assigning} blah blah blah
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\end{document}
```

Now I want it to show like this [6-8] but it is showing like this  [6, 7, 8].

What am I doing wrong? Cite package doesn't work either.

EDIT:1
links to bioinfo.cls

http://arxmliv.kwarc.info/sty/bioinfo.cls
https://github.com/the-virtual-brain/tvb-paper/blob/master/bioinfo.cls

Comment: Why do you have two separate `\bibliographystyle` instructions?

Comment: @Mico... back in time when i wasn't using natbib, my references didn't appear in ordered manner, so along with \bibliographystyle{plain}, I had to use \bibliographystyle{unsrt} so order them in ascending order in my paper.

Comment: use `unsrtnat` for the `\bibliographystyle`

Comment: just `unsrtnat` ? or `plainnat` too?

Comment: if you want them unsorted just use `unsrtnat`, if you want them sorted just use `plainnat`.

Comment: @Guido.. 
if I use `plainnat`. I get this
**Weiller [1998], Cokus et al. [2007], Pellegrini et al. [1999].**
If i use  `unsrtnat`. I again get this
**Weiller [1998], Cokus et al. [2007], Pellegrini et al. [1999].**

Comment: That is to say I lose even the one thing i was doing right. The numeric form that is.

Comment: The class loads `natbib` without options, this is the reason why to lose the numeric format. One option is to edit the class file and to add the `natbib` options at line 827 of the class file (i.e., `\RequirePackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}`)

Comment: Thanks a million and another million! Works like a charm! If you can write it in the answers. It would be more visible for newbies like me.

Comment: @Guido Please make that an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `bioinfo` loads `natbib` without any options, thus the default format for citation is numeric.  An option is to modify how `natbib` is loaded by the class. Thus one can make a copy of the class file (let us say call `my-bioinfo.cls` and then edit line 827.  The new line 827 should be

```
\RequirePackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
```